# error perfect forwarding a lamda - discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++17, perfect-forwarding

Given this code: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/z3bEPa)

I am passing a lambda and a parameter pack and forwarding it to std::thread's constructor.

Here is a code snippet:

```
template<typename Functor, class... Args>
std::thread create_fifo_thread(int sch_priority, const Functor&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    std::thread th(std::forward<Functor>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
//    std::thread th(func, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    set_fifo_pri(th, sch_priority);
    return th;
}
```

You can see when I do it like this I get the error, but when I switch the commented line in it works fine. Please follow the link to see the error its quite long! - but I can print here if needd.

Here is how I call it:

```
auto fth = create_fifo_thread(10, [](int count){ return test(count); }, 10);
```

Note that `test()` is `void test(int count)` - very trivial function.

My questions are/is: do I need to try to perfect forward here? - and what qualifiers am I discarding? - what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Note also that you need `std::reference_wrapper` to really pass by reference.

Comment: and also, typo: missing `;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 sorry which part are you referring to for the ref_wrapper? - I did not understand

Comment: I mean that `std::thread` will do copy of its argument, so perfect forwarding is less useful that it may appears.

Comment: @Jarod42 good point, I suppose I could return a unique pointer to the thread...  But I am still not sure where you advise to put the std::ref_wrapper? - probably I am being slow here!

Comment: In your example, you don't need `std::reference_wrapper`. (You need it for something like `std::atomic<int> counter{0}; create_fifo_thread(10, [](int& count){ ++count; }, std::ref(counter));`).

Comment: @code_fodder To answer one of your questions, you discarded the `const` on the `func` argument when you called `std::forward` with a non-const `Functor` template parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perfect forwarding use `Functor&& func` - not `const Functor&& func`